# Thread starvation while locking in a loop in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have an application which is acquiring a lock in a loop in one thread to
perform some task. There's also a second thread that also wants to acquire the lock from
time to time. The problem is, this second thread barely even gets the chance to
perform it's work, as the first one almost always locks first. I hope the
following code will clarify what I'm trying to say:

```
import time
from threading import Lock, Thread

lock = Lock()


def loop():
    while True:
        with lock:
            time.sleep(0.1)

thread = Thread(target=loop)
thread.start()

before = time.time()
lock.acquire()
print('Took {}'.format(time.time() - before))
```

If the application gets to `print` you'll notice that it needed way more than
just 0.1s. But sometimes it also happens that it just waits indefinitely. I've tested this both in Python 2.7.11 and Python 3.4.3 on Debian Linux 8 and it works identically.

This behaviour is counter-intuitive for me. After all when the lock is released
in `loop`, the `lock.acquire` was already waiting for its release and it should
immediately acquire the lock. But instead it looks like the loop gets to acquire
the lock first, even though it wasn't waiting for its release at all at the
release moment.

The solution I've found is to sleep between each loop iteration in unlocked state, but that
doesn't strike me as an elegant solution, neither does it explain to me what's
happening.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want deterministic behavior instead of mutual exclusion, then `Lock` is not the right object to use..  You might be able to force a task switch by issuing a `time.sleep(0)` but I'm sure that would fail on some platforms..

Comment: Well, I've figured out that when I have just two threads then when one waits for a lock it will always get it right after the another unlocks. What I wonder is why it isn't so. Also, what do you think would be a proper object to use?

Comment: Hard to say why it's happening, but if I were to guess it would have something to do with task switches happening such that the while loop manages to call aquire again before the relase code has reached the point where it selects among waiting threads. But that's just guessing.

Comment: it might also be a linux thing ;-)  check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103847/pausing-two-python-threads-while-a-third-one-does-stuff-with-locks

Comment: @JakubS. I can't reproduce your issue on python 3.4.4 and 3.5.1(windows)

Comment: @Vince Yes, because it is unrelated to Python. It is related to OS and its thread scheduling algorithm though.

Comment: It's the scheduler. I have been running into this issue several times. Looping constructs with locks. The lock is very hard to acquire from another thread.

Comment: What happens if you sleep like 2 or 10 seconds?

Comment: @totoro The results are the same.

Comment: @JakubS. Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this is due to OS thread scheduling. My guess is that either OS gives very high priority to cpu intensive threads (whatever that means) **or** chosing a next thread to acquire the lock (done by the OS) takes more time than actually acquiring the lock by the second thread. Either way not much can be deduced without knowing the internals of the OS.

But it's not GIL since this code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mutex;

void my_thread() {
    int counter = 100;
    while (counter--) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mutex);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::thread t1(my_thread);
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // added sleep to ensure that the other thread locks lock first
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mutex);
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto diff = end - start;
        std::cout << "Took me " << diff.count() << std::endl;
    }
    t1.join();
    return 0;
};
```

which is just a C++11 version of your code gives exactly the same result (tested on Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: You can also avoid starvation with a FIFO type lock

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading in CPython is somewhat complicated. To make the implementation (of memory management among other things) easier,  CPython has a built-in "Global Interpreter Lock". This lock ensures that only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode.

A thread will release the GIL when it does I/O or reaches into a C extension. And if it doesn't the GIL will be taken from it up at certain intervals. So if a thread is busy spinning like your thread is, at one point it will be forced to give up the GIL. And you would *expect* that in that case another thread gets a chance to run. But because Python threads are basically operating system threads, the OS also has a say in scheduling. And there a thread that is constantly busy may get a higher priority and so get more chances to run.

For a more in-depth look, check out the video [understanding the Python GIL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obt-vMVdM8s) by David Beazley.

Comment: It is not GIL (the idea was smelly to me from the begining), see my answer.

Comment: @freakish Read again.

Comment: I've read it several times. GIL is completely unrelated to the problem. Talking about it is confusing and does not help at all. Your whole answer should be reduced to 1 sentence: `the OS also has a say in scheduling`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @freakish's useful answer, for me the practical solution was to add a tiny sleep right before the greedy thread acquires the lock. In your case:

```
def loop():
    while True:
        # give time for competing threads to acquire lock
        time.sleep(0.001)
        with lock:
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Sleeping for 0 seconds (as suggested in the comments) didn't work for me.